British TV show with linen puppets with nature-themed names
I watched this VHS when I was about 9 (I'm 25 now) - but I know it was from much much further back as it was grainy looking and I think black and white..
It was a british programme, a group of puppets, with normal body and faces. They had the texture of rough brown linen, with faces drawn/painted on. They had british accents, softly spoken and I'm pretty sure all voiced by one man.
All I remember was the opening credits had a gate opening scene, in like a countryside or field. The characters had naturey names like "Mr Oak" and "Mrs Bramble" - I made those up but they were something like that. I think I remember the word "hollow" in the title but google provides nothing...
There was one episode where the main character fell and hurt himself I think. 
Sorry, that's all I got. I've been searching high and low and come up with nada so far.

Have you tried searching for old children's programmes? I'm sure there are many lists out there you can peruse.

Probably not what you're looking for, but this question reminded me of Woolly Valley http://www.nzonscreen.com/title/woolly-valley-1981

Try Pogles wood, the herbs or the woodentops.http://www.pogleswood.org/  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Herbs  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Woodentops_(TV_series)

I think I know what you mean. Is it Rocky Hollow?
I used to love it as a kid
http://www.toonhound.com/rockyhol.htm

Acorn, Sycamore, Mr Oak, Miss Myrtle, Conker
        and Rosie Woodpigeon dwelled in the sunny woodland glade of Rocky Hollow. 
        The models were designed to look like seed people and were constructed out
        of rough tan material 



OMG IT WAS ROCKY HOLLOW!!!!! Thank you SO much Mat!! <3

Might it be The Pogles, from the late, great Oliver Postgate?
A blast from my own past :)


Sounds like Camberwick Green or one of its closely related shows narrated by Brian Cant.
List of characters here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camberwick_Green
Other nearby places also had series, Camberwick Green was about village life, the nearest town was Trumpton and the local aristocrat lived at Chigley.
Together they are known as the Trumptonshire trilogy, by Gordon Murray.

It's Pogles Wood.  Can't remember these characters names but there was a boy/pixy? called Pippin and a rabbit (I think) called Tog.

Unfortunately not.  Other elements of the question mean that it isn't Pogles Wood.   Pippin was the son of Pogle and not a pixie.
